# VBA - How do I pass a variable into a network file path

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA and honestly do not know what I am doing.

Problem:
I need a macro to go to a file networks path based on an user's input. But I do not know if it is possible to pass two variables into a Network path. Or if there is some other way to do this.

Ex) The user would choose the FileName they want and the IP Address of where that file is located in the Master Excel sheet from a drop down list. There are many types of files and IP Addresses, so I do not want to hard code them all into the macro.

Currently all I have is the below hard code that states the actual location (IP Address) and FileName.

```
Dim vPID As Variant      vPID = Shell("notepad.exe ""\\105.xxx.xx.xx\C:\FileName""", vbNormalFocus)
```

Can someone point me to a good resource that I can research? I have been searching online for hours and cannot find anything that directly relates to what I want to do.

I tried the below, but the network path cannot be found due to how I incorrectly inserted the variables.

Note: The file that will be opened is in XML format that will be opened in notepad and not converted to .xls.

Note: ToolID references an IP Address in the cell range "G6"
FileName references a cell range in "I3"

```
Dim ToolID As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim vPID As Variant
Dim GetFile As Workbook

Set GetFile = ThisWorkbook
FileName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G6").Value
ToolID = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I3").Value

vPID = Shell("notepad.exe ""\\ToolID\C:\FileName""", vbNormalFocus)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how `Shell()` works, but generally, you have to "break out" the part where your variables will go.  It should be something like this:

```
vPID = Shell("notepad.exe ""\\" & ToolID & "\C:\" & FileName & """", vbNormalFocus)
```

Similar to how if you want variables in a sentence like "This sentence has [var1] spaces in it. That's [var2]" would be:

```
myString = "This sentence has " & var1 & " spaces in it. That's " & var2
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try this tomorrow and see if this is works within the shell ().

Comment: @mplh2008 - there is no difference between string concatenations "within the shell" and anywhere else - all you are doing is creating a single string, and then that is being passed as a parameter to the shell.  For ease of debugging, you may like to make it two commands - `commandString = "notepad.exe ""\\" & ToolID & "\C:\" & FileName & """"` and `vPID = Shell(commandString, vbNormalFocus)`.

Comment: @mplh2008 glad it's working! I would take YowE3k's suggestion into consideration as it would make it look a little more "clean" and help when troubleshooting.